# Spark multiple dynamic aggregate functions, countDistinct not working

Tags: scala, apache-spark, count, apache-spark-sql, distinct

Aggregation on Spark dataframe with multiple dynamic aggregation operations.

I want to do aggregation on a Spark dataframe using Scala with multiple dynamic aggregation operations (passed by user in JSON). I'm converting the JSON to a `Map`.

Below is some sample data:

```
colA    colB    colC    colD
1       2       3       4
5       6       7       8
9       10      11      12
```

The Spark aggregation code which I am using:

```
var cols = ["colA","colB"]
var aggFuncMap = Map("colC"-> "sum", "colD"-> "countDistinct")
var aggregatedDF = currentDF.groupBy(cols.head, cols.tail: _*).agg(aggFuncMap)
```

I have to pass `aggFuncMap` as `Map` only, so that user can pass any number of aggregations through the JSON configuration.

The above code is working fine for some aggregations, including `sum`, `min`, `max`, `avg` and `count`.

However, unfortunately this code is not working for `countDistinct` (maybe because it is camel case?).

When running the above code, I am getting this error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'countdistinct'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's currently not possible to use `agg` with `countDistinct` inside a `Map`. From the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/RelationalGroupedDataset.html#agg-scala.collection.immutable.Map-) we see:

> The available aggregate methods are avg, max, min, sum, count.

---

A possible fix would be to change the `Map` to a `Seq[Column]`,

```
val cols = Seq("colA", "colB")
val aggFuncs = Seq(sum("colC"), countDistinct("colD"))
val df2 = df.groupBy(cols.head, cols.tail: _*).agg(aggFuncs.head, aggFuncs.tail: _*)
```

but that won't help very much if the user are to specify the aggregations in a configuration file.

Another approach would be to use [`expr`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#expr-java.lang.String-), this function will evaluate a string and give back a column. However, `expr` won't accept `"countDistinct"`, instead `"count(distinct(...))"` needs to be used.
This could be coded as follows:

```
val aggFuncs = Seq("sum(colC)", "count(distinct(colD))").map(e => expr(e))
val df2 = df.groupBy(cols.head, cols.tail: _*).agg(aggFuncs.head, aggFuncs.tail: _*)
```